# Optimizing sql query to get rid of spool space issue

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a following problem.

I have three tables
  1.)All users historical table that records all instances that ever run
  2.)All instances table that records all instances ever run
  3.)Instances table where i can identify the active instances

My goal is to get all users that are part of an active instance.

The problem is that all users table holds 137 billion records so it is impossible to join it with one query.

My best query so far:

```
SELECT allcontact.users FROM  allcontact 
WHERE EXISTS
            (
            SELECT  1  
            FROM allinstances
            WHERE allinstances.instances = allcontact.instances
            AND EXISTS
                    (
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM  activeinstances
                    WHERE 1 = 1
                    AND activeinstances.end_date> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                    AND activeinstances.run_id = allinstances.run_id
                    AND activeinstances.run_date = allinstances.run_date))
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY allcontact.users ORDER BY allcontact.users DESC)=1
```

At the moment it works with following logic. It checks all the runs where the end_date is bigger than current date and then it takes all the instances from the allinstance table where those conditions are met. However this query ends up with spool space issue.

The reason why i need to do this is that one run might contain instances that are not present in the activeinstances table so i need to take all runs based on the run date and run_id and find those from all instances table. This query gives me correct results but i am only able to run it if I reduce the number of results which i cannot do on end production.

I am able to run it if i create a volatile table with all the instances and join it then with allcontact table. However in the end product where this query should go, i am not able to create volatile tables.

If anybody can come up with suggestions on how to run this with one query, i would be grateful.

The enviroment is IBM campaign that sits on top of teradata.

Thanks!

*EDIT* Added more content

Primary keys:
allcontact table 
  PK:cntct_id

allinstances table
  PK:instances

activeinstances table
  PK:instances

Explain plan:

```
SELECT allcontact.users FROM allcontact AS cntct 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM allinstances  WHERE allinstances.instances = allcontact.instances      AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  activeinstances WHERE 1 = 1 AND activeinstances.end_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND activeinstances.run_id = allinstances.run_id AND activeinstances.run_date = allinstances.run_date)) QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY allcontact.users ORDER BY allcontact.users DESC)=1;

 This query is optimized using type 2 profile cp_rowkey, profileid
 10006.   1) First, we lock ACTIVEINSTANCES for access, we
     lock ALLCONTACT in view allcontact for
     access, and we lock allinstances for access.   2) Next, we execute the following steps in parallel.
       1) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from allinstances
          by way of an all-rows scan with a condition of (
          "allinstances.TRTMNT_TYPE_CODE <> 'I'") into
          Spool 3 (all_amps), which is redistributed by the hash code
          of (allinstances.RUN_DATE,
          allinstances.RUN_ID) to all AMPs.  The size of
          Spool 3 is estimated with low confidence to be 4,612,364 rows
          (119,921,464 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is
          0.50 seconds.
       2) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from
          ACTIVEINSTANCES by way of an all-rows
          scan with a condition of (
          "(CAST((ACTIVEINSTANCES.END_DATE)
          AS TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE))> TIMESTAMP '2017-08-28
          01:55:35.110000+00:00'") into Spool 4 (all_amps), which is
          redistributed by the hash code of (
          ACTIVEINSTANCES.RUN_DATE,
          ACTIVEINSTANCES.RUN_ID) to all AMPs.
          Then we do a SORT to order Spool 4 by row hash and the sort
          key in spool field1 eliminating duplicate rows.  The size of
          Spool 4 is estimated with no confidence to be 132,623 rows (
          4,907,051 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.01
          seconds.
       3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from ALLCONTACT
          in view allcontact by way of an all-rows scan
          with no residual conditions into Spool 5 (all_amps) fanned
          out into 17 hash join partitions, which is built locally on
          the AMPs.  The input table will not be cached in memory, but
          it is eligible for synchronized scanning.  The size of Spool
          5 is estimated with high confidence to be 138,065,479,155
          rows (3,451,636,978,875 bytes).  The estimated time for this
          step is 1 minute and 19 seconds.   3) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 3 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 4 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan.  Spool 3 and Spool 4 are joined using a single
     partition inclusion hash join, with a join condition of (
     "(TRTMNT_TYPE_CODE NOT IN ('I')) AND ((RUN_DATE =
     RUN_DATE) AND (RUN_ID = RUN_ID ))").  The result goes into
     Spool 7 (all_amps), which is redistributed by the hash code of (
     allinstances.INSTANCES) to all AMPs.  Then we do a
     SORT to order Spool 7 by the sort key in spool field1 eliminating
     duplicate rows.  The size of Spool 7 is estimated with no
     confidence to be 496,670 rows (12,416,750 bytes).  The estimated
     time for this step is 9.84 seconds.   4) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 7 (Last Use) by way of
     an all-rows scan into Spool 6 (all_amps) fanned out into 17 hash
     join partitions, which is duplicated on all AMPs.  The size of
     Spool 6 is estimated with no confidence to be 1,862,512,500 rows (
     46,562,812,500 bytes).   5) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 5 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 6 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan.  Spool 5 and Spool 6 are joined using a inclusion
     hash join of 17 partitions, with a join condition of ("INSTANCES =
     INSTANCES").  The result goes into Spool 2 (all_amps), which is
     built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 2 is estimated with
     no confidence to be 34,652,542,903 rows (797,008,486,769 bytes).
     The estimated time for this step is 23.71 seconds.   6) We do an all-AMPs STAT FUNCTION step from Spool 2 (Last Use) by
     way of an all-rows scan into Spool 12 (Last Use), which is
     redistributed by hash code to all AMPs.  The result rows are put
     into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.
     The size is estimated with no confidence to be 650,694,038 rows (
     24,075,679,406 bytes).   7) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.   -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.
     BEGIN RECOMMENDED STATS FOR FINAL PLAN->
     -- "COLLECT STATISTICS COLUMN (RUN_ID ,RUN_DATE) ON
     ACTIVEINSTANCES" (High Confidence)
     -- "COLLECT STATISTICS COLUMN (CAST((END_DATE) AS
     TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE)) AS
     ACTIVEINSTANCES ON
     ACTIVEINSTANCES" (High Confidence)
     <- END RECOMMENDED STATS FOR FINAL PLAN
```

The query that works currently:

```
SELECT Distinct t.users
FROM
(SELECT users, instances FROM allcontacts
JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT Run_dt
FROM activeinstances
WHERE activeinstances.end_date> Cast(Current_Timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)
) AS drv on drv.Run_dt = allcontacts.run_dt) as t
JOIN
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT allinstances.instances
   FROM allinstances
   JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT run_date, run_id
           FROM activeinstances
           WHERE activeinstances.end_date> Cast(Current_Timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)
        ) AS activeinstances
   ON activeinstances.run_id = allinstances.run_id
   AND activeinstances.run_date = allinstances.run_date
  ) AS dt 
ON dt.instances = allcontact.instances
```

Comment: Can you add DDL&PKs/FKs plus Explain of the current query?

Comment: Hi @dnoeth added more content for this.

Comment: Can you add `allinstances.instances = activeinstances.instances` to the inner most EXISTS? What's the data type of `activeinstances.end_date`, DATE ot TIMESTAMP? What's the actual number of rows vs. the estimated 132,623 for `activeinstances.end_date> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`? Btw, your PKs are probably the Primary Indexes, not the logical Primary Keys...

Comment: Hi @dnoeth you are right about the Primary Keys that they are actually Primary Indexes. I don't see any Primary keys defined as it is. 'activeinstances.end_date' is TIMESTAMP. WIth following query  
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM  activeinstances
   WHERE 1 = 1
   AND activeinstances.end_date> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  i get only 1054 rows.

Comment: If i add this condition Allinstances.instances = activeinstances.instances, it won't pickup the instances that are part of run_id, run_date and are present in allinstances but are not present in activeinstances view.

Answer (score 0):

This is too much for a comment:

This query can't utilize your current Primary Indexes, not a big problem for the two smaller tables, but for the huge one.

You can try to lower the estimated number of rows using a Derived Table instead of double EXISTS, maybe this changes the final join type:

```
SELECT allcontact.users
FROM allcontact 
JOIN
 (
   -- what's the estimated vs. actual number of rows?
   -- check if one of the recommended stats helps to get closer to the actual number
   SELECT DISTINCT allinstances.instances
   FROM allinstances
   JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT run_date, run_id
           FROM activeinstances
           WHERE activeinstances.end_date> Cast(Current_Timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)
        ) AS activeinstances
   ON activeinstances.run_id = allinstances.run_id
   AND activeinstances.run_date = allinstances.run_date
  ) AS dt 
ON dt.instances = allcontact.instances

-- Assuming you actual Select list includes other columns besides `allcontact.users`
-- otherwise you can switch to `DISTINCT` instead    
QUALIFY Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY allcontact.users ORDER BY allcontact.users DESC)=1
```

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, your query takes a lot less spool than my previous one but still too much. Did some more research and the run_date is available in allcontacts as well and it is partitioned column if that would help going forward. Thank you already for your input so far!

Comment: @puputtiap: adding `run_date` to the join might help. What about the estimated vs. actual number of rows in the Derived Table, is it getting close? Did the join type change?

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, I actually manage to run the query by creating another derived table and reducing the amount of records in allcontacts. I will edit my question and add the query there. Not super efficient but seems to work.